# How to obtain the current date by week of year and week of day

Tags: c#, date

I know the year, the week of the year, and the week of the day.
With this information I want to get the current date.
For example,
Year: 2018
Week of year: 01
Day of week: 3
I want to get the value by 03/01/2018.

Comment: Did you try anything?

Comment: What is `Week of day`? Do you mean `Day of week`? Also, Please note that `Week of year` might be calculated in at least two distinct ways: Either it starts with the first week of the year, or it starts with the first full week of the year. Moreover, a week starts in different days for different cultures. For christian based cultures, the week starts on Monday. For Jewish, it starts on Sunday. There are a lot of things you need to consider before you can calculate the date based on this data.

Comment: 2018 is not a good example for this, since January 1st is a Monday (start of week for christian based cultures), Try 2019 as an example. What date would be the 4th day of the 2nd week in 2019? The way I see it the result could either be the 9th, 10th, 16th or 17th in January, based on the first week of the year is either partial or full, and the first day of the month is either Sunday or Monday. Of course, nothing is preventing you to set the first day of the week in any weekday.

Comment: @ZoharPeled not all christian based cultures starts on Monday. Brazil is a christian country and week starts in Sunday.

Comment: @Magnetron Thanks for the info. I didn't know that.

Comment: Monday is the first day of the week according to the international standard ISO 8601, but in the US, Canada, and Japan (and probably some other places) it's counted as the second day of the week.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this method to get the first day of a week:

```
public static DateTime FirstDateOfWeek(int year, int weekOfYear, System.Globalization.CultureInfo ci = null)
{
    if (ci == null) ci = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture;
    DateTime jan1 = new DateTime(year, 1, 1);
    int daysOffset = ((int)ci.DateTimeFormat.FirstDayOfWeek) - ((int) jan1.DayOfWeek);
    DateTime firstWeekDay = jan1.AddDays(daysOffset);
    int firstWeek = ci.Calendar.GetWeekOfYear(jan1, ci.DateTimeFormat.CalendarWeekRule, ci.DateTimeFormat.FirstDayOfWeek);
    if (firstWeek <= 1|| firstWeek > 50 )
        weekOfYear--;

    return firstWeekDay.AddDays(weekOfYear * 7);
}
```

Then you just need to add `dayOfWeek - 1` to it:

```
int year = 2018;
int weekOfYear = 01;
int dayOfWeek = 03;
DateTime firstDateOfWeek = FirstDateOfWeek(year, weekOfYear);
DateTime desiredResult = firstDateOfWeek.AddDays(dayOfWeek - 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

First get the day of the year, by multiplying the week of year * 7 plus the day of week:

```
int dayOfYear = weekOfYear*7 + dayOfWeek
```

Then get the datetime that corresponds to the first day of your year, and add the number of days to that:

```
DateTime myDate = new DateTime(year, 1, 1).AddDays(dayOfYear - 1);
```

To get it as a string with the format you want, use this:

```
string myString = myDate.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
```

Comment: There is some flaw in your logic, for year 2019, first week of the year, third day of week it gives 2019-01-10 which is a Thursday. Thursday is the 4th or 5th day of the week, depending of the culture.